# Calling public "non-static" variable or method without instantiating its class

Tags: java, non-static

Is there any way to call the public non-static variable or method without instantiating its class java...

Comment: Why don't you make the method `static`?

Answer (score 9):

In Java, there is no way to call   non static variables,  i.e instance members without `instance`.

There is a reason for that, from [Understanding Instance and Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

> When a number of objects are created from the same class blueprint, they each have their own distinct copies of instance variables.

Where as static methods belongs to Class not to the specific `instance`

Answer (score 2):

No , cause it defeats the very purpose of static

Answer (score 2):

No, it does not make sense to call a instance variable without a instance.

Answer (score 1):

not thats not possible,you can not call non static methods with out creating instance.but if you do not want to create instance and want to directly call then make those methods as static

Answer (score 1):

You need an object to call non-static methods, but it doesn't have to be an object of the class where the method is defined - it can also be an object of a subclass of that class.

This can be useful if it's hard to put your hands on an object of that class - for example if it's constructor has parameters that are hard to obtain and can't be nulled, or if you need to create the object from a method in another object that is hard to obtain itself. In these cases, you can extend the class with your own class, that has an easier constructor, create an object of that subclass and call it yourself.

Do keep in mind that this method is hackish and dangerous and that it violates a core principle of OOP. Your subclass skips the regular construction of the class it extends, and since that construction is so complex(if it wasn't you would simply have instantiated it directly) you can be fairly certain that the original construction process was important, and that some - if not most - of that object's functionality will not work correctly: throw an exception if you are lucky, and if you are less lucky it might yield bad results or even corrupt other objects. Even if that one method you need functions correctly with this hack, it is possible future changes to that class will make that method depend on proper construction, and that will break your code.

So - **use at your own risk!**

```
public class MyNewClass extends ClassWithNonStaticMethod{
    public MyNewClass(){
        //Not doing proper construction
    }
}

//somewhere in your code:
new MyNewClass().nonStaticMethod();
```

Comment: Added it to the answer

Comment: I am accessing getter() from ClassWithNonStaticMethod by using the above code, but the getter() returns null, I am not getting values from ClassWithNonStaticMethod  class

Comment: I have Constructor in ClassWithNonStaticMethod, that performs some designs

Comment: I have added new default constructor to ClassWithNonStaticMethod, ClassWithNonStaticMethod (){},because the MyNewClass() extends this , so it prompts me to override the super constructor

Comment: This is exactly what I warned you about - when you hack the construction of the object, it is not constructed properly and methods may not return the correct result. This hack is only useful for calling methods that should have been static in the first place. This is clearly not the case here - there is no way to do what you want, because what you want doesn't make any sense. a getter is for querying the state of an object. If you don't have an object there is no state to query. In a sense, `null` **is** the correct result - the properties of an object that does not exist are "nothing".

Comment: I have created one class to store the values of non-static variable using getter() and setter() in my class, I have using HashMap to store the non-static values with some unique key, this HaspMap is used to get the values of non- static variable.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your question, no, you can't.  Java isn't designed to let you do that.

However, I think its more important to ask:  **Why do you feel you need to do this?**

If you don't have control over this class (ie, its a library class), and you feel a need to do this, you are probably using the library incorrectly.

If you can modify the class, make it static.